# How can I remove an energy gel stain from my carpet?

Tags: cleaning, carpet

I appear to have a small solid 'clump' on my carpet. I'm guessing that it is from an [energy gel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_gel), which is basically corn syrup mixed with water. Usually I'm pretty good on carpet stains (hey, I'm clumsy), but I have no idea how to remove this one. It's fairly solidly set.

If it's worth anyway, I've had this stuff dry all over clothing before and it's come out the of the washing machine fine. Of course, that's not quite a wollen carpet. I was thinking of blotting with vinegar.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for vinegar yet. The stuff is very water soluble.
If you get the carpet too wet, you'll just transfer the sugars to the floor under the carpet.
I'd put a wet, not slopping wet, towel on it, and let it sit overnight. The sugars should be drawn into the towel. It might take several applications. Once you've got most of it, go ahead and attack w a wet sponge/vinegar.

Comment: Quick update - this worked amazing! In fact I didn't even really need to use vinegar. So thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Its made to remove pet urine odors and stains from carpet and furniture, but Natures Miracle works great for just about any organic item that gets spilled.  The enzymes break down the sugars and proteins even if they are under the carpet where you can't clean them - it takes about 1-2 weeks to fully work so its not a quick fix though.